# Barplot ignores colorpalette

Tags: r

I calculated means from different columns in different dataframes and put those into another dataframe to plot them. From this code

```
 res <- structure(list(`2012` = 6.86537485268066, 
                       `2013` = 5.91282899425944, 
    `2014` = 4.45070377934188),
     .Names = c("2012", "2013", "2014"),    
     row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame")
colors<- c("yellow", "red", "green")
ticks <- c(0,8)
barplot(as.matrix(res), ylim=ticks, ylab="Mean Ratio", 
        width=0.5, col=colors, xlab="Year", main="Mean ratio per year")
```

i get a uni-coloured barplot in yellow.

Same is true for

```
myMat<-matrix(runif(3), ncol=3) 
barplot(myMat, col=colors)
```

Why is this? I managed to do the graph with `ggplot` and `reshape`, but it still bothers me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you hand `barplot()` something that looks like a matrix (i.e. it has dimensions, or more specifically a `dim` attribute), it colors each *segment* according to `cols`.  What it is doing in your case is assuming that each of the values is the first segment in its category.  To convert this simple data frame to a vector, try `unlist()` ...

```
barplot(unlist(res), ylim=ticks, ylab="Mean Ratio", 
        width=0.5, col=colors, xlab="Year",
        main="Mean ratio per year")
```

Answer (score 3):

Barplot assumes that you use stacked bars, and you have only one category.
If you specify `beside=TRUE`, that is no longer the case:

```
barplot(as.matrix(res), ylim=ticks, ylab="Mean Ratio", beside=TRUE,
        width=0.5, col=colors, xlab="Year", main="Mean ratio per year" )
```